# Storing nested javascript objects in redis - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, redis, memcached

I recently switched from memcached to redis in nodejs. The thing I liked in node-memcached was that I can save the whole javascript object in the memory. Sadly I couldn't do this in redis. For example, I got the following object:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Hello world!",
    author: "admin",
    user: {
        "yolololo" : {
             "id": "352asdsafaseww",
             "server": 5,
             "data" : {
                  x: 1, 
                  y: 1,
                  z: 50
             }
        },
        "yolol" : {
             "id": "358dsa",
             "server": 7
        }
    }
}
```

with the [3rd-Eden/node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) I could just do:

```
memcached.set("obj", obj, 12345, function(err) { });
```

and then

```
memcached.get("obj", function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And I'll get the object I saved, just the way it is.

The problem with redis is that if I save the object like this:

```
redisclient.set("obj", obj, redis.print);
```

When I get the value with

```
redisclient.get("obj", function(err, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

The output is just string containing `[object Object]`.

Yeah I understand redis is text-based protocol and it's trying to do obj.toString(), but seems memcached take care of objects and redis don't.
I thought I could just do:

```
redisClient.set("obj", JSON.stringify(obj));
```

but I'm not sure if this will be good, because there will be insane high I/O and I'm not sure if the JSON obj->string will be bottleneck ( 10k+ request/second ).

Both Memcached and Redis store the data as string, but does redis have built-in feature for converting objects?

Comment: I think **memcached** stores data as string. **node-memcached** does (de)serialization process automatically.

Comment: @fardjad Yeah, you're right, but does Redis have such build-in process or I need to convert it manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all [redis](/questions/tagged/redis) only supports the following [data types](http://redis.io/topics/data-types):

1. String
2. List
3. Set
4. Hash
5. Sorted set

You'll need to store objects as string in both **redis** and [memcached](/questions/tagged/memcached).

[**node-memcached**](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) parses/stringifies the data automatically. But [**node-redis**](https://github.com/mranney/node_redis) doesn't.

However, you can implement your own serialization/deserialization functions for your app.

The way **node-memcached** stringifies an object is [as follows](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/blob/master/lib/memcached.js#L888):

```
if (Buffer.isBuffer(value)) {
    flag = FLAG_BINARY;
    value = value.toString('binary');
} else if (valuetype === 'number') {
    flag = FLAG_NUMERIC;
    value = value.toString();
} else if (valuetype !== 'string') {
    flag = FLAG_JSON;
    value = JSON.stringify(value);
}
```

It also parses the retrieved text [this way](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached/blob/master/lib/memcached.js#L495):

```
switch (flag) {
    case FLAG_JSON:
        dataSet = JSON.parse(dataSet);
        break;
    case FLAG_NUMERIC:
        dataSet = +dataSet;
        break;
    case FLAG_BINARY:
        tmp = new Buffer(dataSet.length);
        tmp.write(dataSet, 0, 'binary');
        dataSet = tmp;
        break;
}
```